# Armature Symmetrize not working

Tags: rigging, armature

My armature does not [`Symmetrize`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/symmetrize.html) even though I think my naming convention is correct.

[image: naming convention]

I'm not sure why it's not working.

[image: picture of my human model]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=rnxnnqG7" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/rnxnnqG7/)

Comment: Had you selected the bones when you tried to symmetrize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your armature is not aligned with the global axis so it won't mirror as you expect, just apply the *Rotation* in *Object* mode. And of course, as Bluder says, select the bones before the symmetrize.

Comment: Thanks mate, works now